# A proof on limit preserving functors.

Tags: category-theory

**Proposition** Consider a category $\mathscr{D}$ with initial object $0$ and a functor $F:\mathscr{D}\longrightarrow\mathscr{A}$. Let us write $0_D:0\longrightarrow D$ for the unique arrow from $0$ to $D$ in $\mathscr{D}$. On these conditions, the limit of $F$ exists and is given by $(F0,(F0_D)_{D\in\mathscr{D}}).\blacksquare$

Now consider the case where $F:\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow\mathscr{B}$ is a functor; fix an object $B$ of $\mathscr{B}$ and let $\varepsilon_B$ be the category of elements of the functor $\mathscr{B}(B,F-):\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow Set$, that is the category having the pairs $\langle A,a\rangle$ with $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and $a:B\longrightarrow FA$ as objects and $\mathscr{A}$-morphisms $f:A\longrightarrow A'$ such that $Ff\circ a=a'$ as morphisms from $\langle A,a\rangle$ to $\langle A',a'\rangle$.

Let $\langle L,\alpha\rangle$ be a reflection of $B$ along $F$ (I don't know if 'reflection' is the standard name, maybe one should call it universal arrow from $B$ to $F$), that is $L$ is an object of $\mathscr{A}$, $\alpha:B\longrightarrow FL$ and this $\langle L,\alpha\rangle$ satisfies the universal property that for every pair $\langle A,a\rangle$, there exists a unique $\mathscr{A}$-morphism $p_{\langle A, a\rangle}$ such that $Fp_{\langle A,a\rangle}\circ\alpha=a$.

Thus $\langle L,\alpha\rangle$ is initial in $\varepsilon_B$ and applying Proposition gives that the forgetbul functor $\Phi_B:\varepsilon_B\longrightarrow\mathscr{A}$ has a limit, which is given by $(L,(p_{\langle A,a\rangle})_{\langle A,a\rangle\in\varepsilon_B})$.

What I can't prove is that $F$ preserves this limit, i.e. that $(FL,(Fp_{\langle A,a\rangle})$ is the limit of $F\circ\Phi_B$. Surely $(FL,(Fp_{\langle A,a\rangle})$ is a cone, since it is the image of a cone, but how can be proved that it is a limit cone? Given a cone $(M,(q_A))$ on $F\circ\Phi_B$, which is the unique factorization $m:M\longrightarrow FL$ such that $Fp_{\langle A,a\rangle}\circ m=q_A$?

Comment: Don't you just apply the same proposition again?

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, of course. Now it is clear to me. Thanks.